# setOnItemClickListener in custom ListView not Work ActionBarSherlock

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm using ActionBar Sherlock and works fine.

This code works fine in 2.x but not in 4.x

The click only works in versions 2.x not working in 4.x versions I've tried many ways and I can not make the click function

what is the problem?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListActivity;

public class Inicio extends SherlockListActivity {
    private ListView mListView;
    private ArrayList<Capitulos> listado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mListView = getListView();

        listado = new ArrayList<Capitulos>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            listado.add(new Capitulos("Titulo " + i, "descripcion " + i));
        }

        AdaptadorTitulares adaptador = new AdaptadorTitulares(Inicio.this);
        setListAdapter(adaptador);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(Inicio.this, "hazlo", 0).show();
            }
        });
    }

    class AdaptadorTitulares extends ArrayAdapter {
        Activity context;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        AdaptadorTitulares(Activity context) {
            super(context, R.layout.lista, listado);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista, null);

            TextView titulo = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.titulo_art);
            titulo.setText(((Capitulos)getItem(position)).getTitulo());
            TextView subtitulo = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.desc_art);
            subtitulo.setText(((Capitulos)getItem(position)).getDescrip());

            return(item);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define it inside the `arrayyAdapter` class as `onClickListener()`:

```
item.setOnClickListener(.....
```

Comment: Probably has nothing to do with your question but why are you defining new `view`(`item`) in `getView` and not inflating `convertView`?